# Golang function parameter without type?

Tags: go, syntax

```
func Match(pattern, name string) (matched bool, err error)
```

- https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Match

Why does `pattern` not have to have a type (like `pattern string`)?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Per https://tour.golang.org/basics/5:

> When two or more consecutive named function parameters share a type,
>   you can omit the type from all but the last.
>
> In this example, we shortened
>
> `x int, y int`
>
> to
>
> `x, y int`

Comment: what a genius move! Absolutelly nothing could go wrong! Every person that will modify type of the last argument will definetelly never forget to add the old type to previous argument. No, it could never happen. What a usefull addition to the language...

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik Golang is statically typed, so a wrong type will be easily detected.